# updating multiple columns with different where clauses

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

So I have the following two update statements:

```
UPDATE table1 SET column1_new = "1" WHERE column1_old IS NOT NULL
UPDATE table1 SET column2_new = "2" WHERE column2_old IS NOT NULL
```

Is there a way to do this in one database call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
UPDATE table1
    SET column1_new = (CASE WHEN column1_old IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE column1_new),
        column2_new = (CASE WHEN column2_old IS NOT NULL THEN 2 ELSE column2_new)
    WHERE column1_old IS NOT NULL OR column2_old IS NOT NULL;
```

However, I think using `update` query is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, you may find the `nvl2` function useful, but you can't avoid using an `or` in the where condition.

```
update table1 set column1_new = nvl2(column1_old, 1, column1_new),
                  column2_new = nvl2(column2_old, 2, column2_new)
where column1_old is not null or column2_old is not null;
```